# ./configure on Cygwin hangs when "checking for a BSD-compatible install..."

Tags: cygwin, configure, autoconf

I use Cygwin in Windows 7 and try to compile a library, [Zyre](https://github.com/zeromq/zyre). My 'configure' file was generated automatically by autoconf. When I run `./configure` from command line for makefile generation, it just says

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install...
```

That is it. There is no errors, no complaints, nothing. I waited >1h and also tried to restart a few times.
What can be wrong? What can I do to make it work?

**Here is some background information about the platform I use:**

`which install` gives `/usr/bin/install`.

The file *config.log* after interruption is:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by libzre configure 1.0.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure 
[..]
install_sh=''
[..]
```

Comment: What does it say in `config.log` after you interrupt it?

Comment: Run `which install`, and see what `install` program `./configure` is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me quite a while to search for the right topic out there in the internet but finally, I found it and also solved the problem. Ptomato and Jack, thanks for the hints!

On the one hand, the `./configure` did not find any BSD-compatible install. On the other hand the `which install` discovered an install. With help of [this blog about autoconf's configure.in](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/misc/tools/configure/configure_in.html) and [this manual about Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Particular-Programs.html) my attention was drawn to configure's `install_sh` variable - which was empty in my case.

The solution was to edit the file `configure` (which I had generated with autoconf before) in the following way: To the line

```
install_sh
```

I added

```
/usr/bin/install -c
```

which gave then

```
install_sh = '/usr/bin/install -c'
```

where `/usr/bin/install` is the output of my `which install` command. Now, my `./configure` command runs.

Comment: This only begs a new question: why was the `configure` script generated this way? See if running `autoconf` will give the same effect, by generating a better `configure` script than the one that came with the source code. It may be that there have been relevant improvements to Autoconf between the time the package's maintainer ran `autoconf` and now. You may find a script called `bootstrap` or `autogen.sh` in the tarball; if so, run these instead, since they will do a more complete job of rebuilding all the generated scripts, Makefiles and such. If this fixes it, let the maintainer know.

Comment: Hey Warren, in fact, my _configure_ script was generated by a file called _autogen.sh_. Sorry, if I did not state that clearly.

Comment: autogen.sh calls autoconf, among other things.